# Powershell to get a DLL name out of it's full path

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a string "....\xyz\abc\0.0\abc.def.ghi.jkl.dll" am trying to get the value of a "abc.def.ghi.jkl.dll" into a variable using powershell.

I am totally new to regex and PS and kinda confused on how to get this done. I read various posts about regex and I am unable to get anything to work

Here is my code,

```
$str = "..\..\xyz\abc\0.0\abc.def.ghi.jkl.dll"

$regex = [regex] '(?is)(?<=\b\\b).*?(?=\b.dll\b)'
$result = $regex.Matches($str)
Write-Host $result
```

I would like to get "abc.def.ghi.jkl.dll" into $result. Could someone please help me out

Comment: If this is a true file path you should not need regex. You could use something along the lines of `resolve-path $str`

Comment: This was a path which was referenced in the csproj file. I got the value as a value from the node which holds it and hence do not get the full path. Thanks for this though, for full paths I ill keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?is)(?<=\\)[^\\]+\.dll\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ2qP1/1)

And no need to use `Matches`, just use a `-match` (or `Match`).

**Explanation**:

- `(?<=\\)` - make sure there is a `\` right before the current position in string
- `[^\\]+` - match 1 or more characters other than `\`
- `\.dll\b` - match a `.` symbol followed by 3 letters `dll` that are followed by a trailing word boundary.

Powershell:

```
$str = "..\..\xyz\abc\0.0\abc.def.ghi.jkl.dll"
[regex]$regex = "(?is)(?<=\\)[^\\]+\.dll\b"
$match = $regex.match($str)  
$result = ""
if ($match.Success)  
{            
    $result = $match.Value
    Write-Host $result
}
```

[image]